# PhoneGap Application - "deviceready" event listener is not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am using vs2012, I am developing a PhoneGap application, in that application I am using the following JavaScript code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady()
    {
       // alert("hh");
        console.log("Entering index.html.onDeviceReady");
        //var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
        var html = "";
        html = html + "<li>" + 'Device Name: ' + device.name + "</li>";
        html = html + "<li>" + 'Device Cordova: ' + device.cordova + "</li>";
        html = html + "<li>" + 'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + "</li>";
        html = html + "<li>" + 'Device UUID: ' + device.uuid + "</li>";
        console.log(html);

        $("#deviceProperties").html(html);
        $("#deviceProperties").listview('refresh');
        console.log("Exiting index.html.onDeviceReady");
    }
```

But the function is not called and is not adding any elements dynamically. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The page must be completely loaded in order to call the `deviceready` event listener otherwise it will not work because the device is not ready. In your script its being called before the page has been loaded completely. Try this:

```
function onLoad()
{
   document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady, true);
}
```

Also in html file change this:

```
<body onload="onLoad();">
```

EDIT: Change the third parameter in `addEventListener` to "`true`".

Comment: But the function is not called and is not adding any elements dynamically. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change the third parameter in addEventListener to "true".

Answer (score 0):

make sure u add the script  `type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"` before your script.